# How do I stop Excel from changing numbers to zero in azure datafactory pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am performing a copy activity in the AZURE data factory to copy the CSV files to data lake. The CSV file first column consists of 16 digit number(Excel support only 15 digits). The original file contains 2021370111105759 but after copying to datalake it showing as 2021370111105750(last digit placing to zero). Anyone please suggest a solution.

Note: After downloading the CSV file from data lake we are able to see 16 digit number in notepad but not in excel

Comment: Yes Karthik, It worked like a charm!!! Thank you so much... appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to view it in notepad correctly there seems to be no issue with ADF copy. However you can use configure derived column using dataflow as a workaround.

### Issue Repro...

I tried the same, if explicitly the type is not mentioned you can use dataflow to detect data types automatically.

[image]

[image]

However after downloading the file from sink it is as below when opened in excel:

[image]

### **Workaround...**

Use `Derived column` in dataflow and set expression as below i.e adding a single Quotation Mark to your column values.

```
concat('\'',id)
```

[image]

[image]

After download and opening locally:

[image]

**Note:** If you are not using ADF and while just storing these kind of data in excel locally, select the cells that you want to enter numbers longer than 15 digits, and then press Ctrl + 1 to display Format Cells dialog. In the popping Format Cells dialog, under Number tab, and select Text from the Category list as shown below:

[image]